# Sorting CSV data into Multidimensional so that data can be modified and saved

Tags: java, arrays, csv, user-interface, multidimensional-array

I am going to try and make this as simple as I can because I confuse myself just thinking about it.

I have data.csv which has 7 comma separated values, and it has 804 rows.

For example:

```
10,100,1000,1,10,100,1050 
10,130,1000,1,12,100,1040 etc
```

My task is to create a GUI Java based program which does the following tasks;

1.Read the CSV, split the lines and store into array (Think im okay with this bit)

2. Once the data has been stored into arrays, certain data must be manipulated. For example;
3. Find the Average of all 'columns' in the CSV -Find the Minimum/maximum values of all columns
4. Plot data to graph (this can be ignored for the time being haha)

So I'm just really confused as to how to PROPERLY store my data into a multidimensional array and ALSO be able to manipulate certain elements of the array. I also need help because I am just confused as to whether I should focus on my GUI, for example creating a button that will load the csv, a button the will calculate averages etc etc.

At the moment I have a just one class that is opening a file (just through the source folder). Reads it line by line, and (I think) is storing it into an array.

I'm not looking for anyone to hold my hand and completely solve this for me. But I just could really do with some help and direction, because I think I am just confusing myself much more.
strong text

Would multiple classes for each of the 'functions' make more sense? For example I have a class for calculating the average, a class for calculating the Min/max etc. and if that is the right way forward, how is best to incorporate that with a GUI.`

Sorry for so many questions and huge thanks to anyone that can help!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    /////////DECLARING ARRAYS/VARIABLES//////
    String line;
    double year[] = new double [5000];
    double month[] = new double [5000];
    double tmax[] = new double [5000];
    double tmin[] = new double [5000];
    double af[] = new double [5000];
    double rain[] = new double [5000];
    double sun[] = new double [5000];
    //////////////////////////////////////////

    ////////////READING THE FILE "SHEFFIELD DATA" *CHANGE TO JUST DATA FOR EASYNESS**//////////
    BufferedReader file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sheffielddata.csv"));
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    ///////////INDEXING THE ARRAY /////////////////
    int index=0;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////


    ////////LOOP TO ENSURE THE FILE READS EACH LINE/////////////////
    while( (line = file.readLine()) != null){
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////APPLY THE SPLIF METHOD///////////////////////////////
        String[] splits = line.split(","); //This will have total of 7 values 
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //////////////ARRAY AND STRINGS///////////////////////  
        String name = splits[0];
        int[] intArray = new int[7];

        double value0 = Double.parseDouble(splits[0]);
        double value1 = Double.parseDouble(splits[1]);
        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(splits[2]);
        double value3 = Double.parseDouble(splits[3]);
        double value4 = Double.parseDouble(splits[4]);
        double value5 = Double.parseDouble(splits[5]);
        double value6 = Double.parseDouble(splits[6]);

        year[index] = value0;
        month[index] = value1;
        tmax[index] = value2;
        tmin[index] = value3;
        af[index] = value4;
        rain[index] = value5;
        sun [index] = value6;

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }//LOOP ENDS READING THE CSV FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, and I'm open to being wrong on this, when I think of creating multiple classes I create classes for each different object I'm attempting to encapsulate.  In your case, you ask if you should create a different class for each of your calculations.  In your case, I think you'd be fine with having all of your calculations performed in one class, but I would separate this class from where you construct the GUI.

So, if it were me and I was attempting to do this assignment in a neat and pretty way, I'd have the following classes:

1) An InformationArray class - in this class I would create the methods that would perform my necessary calculations and this class would contain any variables that I need.
2)  A FileReader class that would contain methods for reading in the CSV file.
3) A GUI class in which you could build a nice looking pane to use.
4)  A Driver class that contains your main method/start method.

That's how I would set this up.  Hope this helped.